# has_many :through association with inverse added twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I've created a sample application that enlighten my issue.

Basically, I have a many-to-many association with a STI class:

```ruby
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basket_fruits, inverse_of: :basket
  has_many :fruits, through: :basket_fruits

  has_many :apples, through: :basket_fruits, source: :fruit, class_name: 'Apple'
  has_many :oranges, through: :basket_fruits, source: :fruit, class_name: 'Orange'
  has_many :bananas, through: :basket_fruits, source: :fruit, class_name: 'Banana'
end

class BasketFruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket, inverse_of: :basket_fruits
  belongs_to :fruit, inverse_of: :basket_fruits

  validates :basket, :fruit, presence: true
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basket_fruits, inverse_of: :fruit
  has_many :baskets, through: :basket_fruits

  validates :type, presence: true, inclusion: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']

  validates :baskets, presence: true
end

class Apple < Fruit; end
class Banana < Fruit; end
class Orange < Fruit; end
```

Schema:

```
Basket(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: date time)
BasketFruit(id: integer, fruit_id: integer, basket_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: date time)
Fruit(id: integer, type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

When a new Banana is created using ActiveAdmin, it uses code that's equivalent to:

```
Basket.create
banana = Basket.first.bananas.build(basket_ids: [Basket.first.id])
```

The problem occurring is that this code creates two associations, which can be observed even without saving the Banana:

```
banana.basket_fruits.size
=> 2
```

Why is this occurring, and how to fix it ?

**Update**

Just discovered this. Maybe that's why AR is trying to add the relationship twice, instead of "overriding" as I would have expected:

```
banana = Basket.first.bananas.build
=> #<Banana id: nil, type: "Banana", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

banana.baskets
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

In this case, one would need to have the association pre filled after the call to `#build`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you assigning the basket twice?

```
 Basket.first.bananas.build(basket_ids: [Basket.first.id])
```

I would write this like this:

```
 Basket.first.bananas.build
```

Comment: Validation prevents me from doing this.